# email application

Tags: linux, email, unix

I have several emails to track. One for yahoo, one for google, and many others.
The problem with this is the tracking. It's a hassle because you have to check or refresh each emails every now and then.
I was thinking it would be nice to have an application to just notify if any of my email address has a new message.
I want to know what application in linux that does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most mail applications can integrate using POP3 or IMAP with most major online mail providers.

Comment: ... and can automatically check your accounts, and show notification of new mail. I assume that's what you meant :-).

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using gmail mail fetcher: http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=21288?
Note: Works for up to 5 e-mail addresses.